# Saving Map In Gson

Tags: java, gson

I would like to save/load a map/hashmap into gson without using reflection (Java 9 is restricting this). Also not sure if I can still use the TypeToken since it depends on the reflection libary.

```
private TestMap map = new TestMap();
//Using this as TestMap.class as The Type parm causes ClassCAstException
private class TestMap extends HashMap<Integer, TeleportDialog[]> {}
@Test
public void loadingMapAndCheckingValues(){
    File file = new File("./data/saves/teleports/teleports.gson");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Type token = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, TeleportDialog[]>>(){}.getType(); //This Works but violates what I'm after.
    try {
        Map<Integer, TeleportDialog[]> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(file), token);
        map.forEach((integer, dialogs) -> {
            System.out.println("Key: " + integer);
            for(TeleportDialog d : dialogs){
                System.out.println(d);
            }
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show code you have used

Comment: What do you mean "Java 9 is restricting this"? Do you have any exceptions or errors from JDK 9 to demonstrate this?

Comment: Java 9 Access to the reflection libary changes, In order to use reflection I would have to add run time parameters in order to give access to this, so I want to avoid using reflection.
http://in.relation.to/2017/04/11/accessing-private-state-of-java-9-modules/